# sql how to extract the most common of values from a windowing function

Tags: sql, count, group-by, db2, windowing

I have data that looks like

```
id   channel   amount    date
a   PHONE       50     '1sep2014'
a   PHONE      100     '1oct2014'
a   INTERNET    20     '4oct2014'
b   PHONE       25     '2oct2014'
b   INTERNET    30     '3oct2014'
c   INTERNET    35     '1oct2014'
c   INTERNET    20     '2oct2014'
c   INTERNET   100     '3oct2014'
```

I would like to mark out the most common channel per id in one step if possible.
I know how do this using a group by and self joining, but whats the easiest to do it without using a self join?

I already have a `row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC)` in my first query as I need to get the latest values/ channel etc from this table. I would like to tie it all into the same query if possible.

Comment: Edge case: What answer do you expect for id=b? PHONE, INTERNET, or both?

Comment: NULL or both or random is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with window functions and a `group by`:

```
select id, channel
from (select id, channel, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      group by id, channel
     ) ic
where seqnum = 1;
```